# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "über etwas diskutieren" und "etwas diskutieren"?

Tags: difference, expression

Zum Beispiel

> Wir haben heute Verschiedenes diskutiert.

oder

> Wir haben heute über Verschiedenes diskutiert.

Comment: Beantwortet mein Post deine Frage ...? *flöt* ;)

Answer (score 12):

Ich finde, semantisch ist da kaum ein Unterschied zu erkennen. Es ist mehr so eine Andeutung dessen, was du mit deiner Aussage erreichen möchtest.
Der Unterschied liegt m.E. nicht im Gegenstand der Unterhaltung, sondern in ihrem Verlauf und dem Vorgehen der Teilnehmer. Wenn ich etwas *diskutiere*, dann gehe ich eher systematisch an einen Sachverhalt heran und bin lösungsorientiert (s.a. "ein Problem diskutieren" im mathematisch-naturwissenschaftlichen Kontext). Der Aufmerksamkeitsfokus des (gedachten) Zuhörers wird eher auf dem liegen, was nach dem "ob" kommt.

> Wir haben (lang und breit) diskutiert, ob die neue Weihnachtsgeldregelung im Einklang mit dem Arbeitsrecht ist.

==> Ihr wart sehr gründlich. Das Ergebnis habt ihr im Protokoll festgehalten.

Wenn du sagst, dass du *über* etwas diskutiert hast, dann wird deine Pointe typischerweise eher darauf abzielen, dass da eine längere Debatte stattfand. Mit *über* beziehst du die Art und Weise mit ein, wie die Teilnehmer diskutieren, und implizierst daher eher, dass die Diskussion nicht so zielgerichtet ist, wie du dir das z.B. gerne wünschst. Der Aufmerksamkeitsfokus läge mMn hier eher auf "diskutiert".

**Edith** - Es kann auch sehr gut sein, dass in diesem Fall nur *herum* diskutiert wurde, ohne eine Einigung zu finden!

> Wir haben (lang und breit) darüber diskutiert, ob die neue Weihnachtsgeldregelung im Einklang mit dem Arbeitsrecht ist.

==> Es gab Konflikte bei dieser Diskussion, aber ihr habt natürlich das Ergebnis trotzdem festgehalten.

Comment: Ich würde bei der zweiten Interpretation durchaus soweit gehen, dass es gut sein kann, dass überhaupt kein eindeutiges Ergebnis erzielt wurde.

Comment: Ich sehe das ähnlich wie O. R. Mapper. Sprachintuitiv ohne es etymologisch oder linguistisch begründen zu können, klingt Variante 1 für mich gefühlt mehr nach einem erfolgreichen Diskurs mit Ergebnis(sen). Variante 2 hingegen fühlt sich eher nach Ergebnislosem Diskurs an. bzw. Diskutiert über den Sachverhalt aber nicht dessen Auflösung.

Comment: Ja, da habe ich auch lange überlegt, weil mein Gefühl auch in die gleiche Richtung ging. Man würde sich beim zweiten Fall wohl bestenfalls eine Einigung oder ein Patt abringen. Konnte es aber nicht begründen und meine "Sprachintuition" auch in keine greifbare Form gießen, darum habe ich es erstmal weggelassen. Freut mich aber, dass ich damit nicht alleine stehe!

Answer (score 6):

Ob man sagt

> Wir haben die Klimawende diskutiert.

oder

> Wir haben über die Klimawende diskutiert.

es bedeutet das gleiche. In einigen Fällen geht es m.E. nicht ohne 'über', etwa:

> Wir haben heute über Pofalla diskutiert.

Dagegen würde 'Pofallas Verhalten/Rede/...' auch wieder ohne 'über' gehen.

Comment: Die letzte Anmerkung finde ich interessant. Könnte man das herunterbrechen auf: Subjekt versus Objekt? Ich überlege gerade ob es da ein Gegenbeispiel gibt, aber bisher fällt mir keines ein.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: Subjekt des Satzes ist aber "Wir". Objekt ist mal Pofalla, mal dessen Verhalten/Aussage/Krawatte... .

Comment: es ging nicht um den grammatikalischen Begriff sondern belebt/unbelebt. Aber du hast sicher recht. Im Sätze auseinandernehmen war ich in der Schule schon nicht so gut. Rechtschreibung ging bis zu den Reformen und Reformen der Reformen aber immer ganz gut.

Answer (score 3):

> Wir haben heute ein Thema **diskutiert**

Darunter versteht man, dass ganz normal eine Sache, ein Themenbereich besprochen wurde.

> Wir haben heute **über** Jemand/ein Thema **diskutiert**

Dieser Fall ist zwar in beiden Fällen korrekt, jedoch wird das **über** meistens nur dann benutzt, wenn man über etwas Konkretes spricht wie beispielsweise eine Person oder ein spezifischer Themenbereich.

Dann gibt es noch diesen Fall hier:

> Wir haben heute ein Thema **ausdiskutiert**

**ausdiskutiert** wird dann benutzt, wenn man wie im ersten Fall über ein Thema, eine Sache spricht, aber explizit zu einem Ende gekommen ist. Das bedeutet wenn sich entweder alle einig gewesen sind zum Schluss, oder dass man gesagt hat: "Wir kommen zu keiner Einigung, wir legen das Thema beiseite."

Answer (score 0):

Es gibt bei Verben manchmal gleichbedeutende Doppelkonstruktionen. Das transitive diskutieren wird heute in der Umgangssprache durch "diskutieren über" ersetzt, analog zu "sprechen über".

Answer (score -1):

`Wir haben heute Verschiedenes diskutiert.`

auch häufig ausdiskutieren/ausdiskutiert

Hier wird über das Produkt von etwas diskutiert, z.B. eine Reaktion auf eine Aktion

Beispiel: `Wir haben heute die Ausschreitungen der Polizei bei den Demonstrationen ausdiskutiert`

`Wir haben heute über Verschiedenes diskutiert.`

Hier wird, auf das obige Beispiel bezogen, auf die Aktion (der Ursprung) eingegangen
z.B. `Wir haben heute über Demonstrationen diskutiert`